# MVC Design: How many array controllers do I need?

Tags: cocoa, binding, nsarraycontroller

I have a pretty straightforward MVC design question.

I've got a class with a bunch of properties, and a form to present an instance of the class. Several of the class properties are arrays - some are arrays of NSStrings to be presented in a one-dimensional table view, and some are arrays of sub-objects to be presented in a two-dimensional table view (one column per sub-object property). I don't actually want to do anything with the data in any of these tables - just present the contents in a scrollable, read-only table view.

During my first attempt at bindings, I added an object controller bound to the class instance. Then, I tried to bind each column of each table view to the "selection" member of the class, with a model key path specifying the array property of the instance (and, for the two-dimensional tables, a member of the sub-object). I was surprised that this didn't work for the columns of the one-dimensional tables.

Next, I added one array controller for *every* table, binding it to the "selection" member of the object controller. For the one-dimensional tables, I bound the column to the array controller with no model key path; for the two-dimensional tables, I bound the column to the array controller with a model key path specifying a property of the sub-object. This works - but for a window with seven tables, I have *seven* array controllers! That feels like overkill, since the tables aren't doing anything other than presenting data.

My question is simple: Is my design in line with good MVC practice - do I really *need* all of these array controllers? Or is there a simpler way to specify my bindings (for one-dimensional and/or two-dimensional tables) that will enable me to eliminate some array controllers? When I have an array of strings in an object to be displayed in a one-column table, it feels like overkill to use an array controller bound to the object and the table.

As an ancillary question - do I really need to worry about excessive array controllers? Are they lightweight objects that I should use liberally, or resource-intensive objects that I should conserve, especially in limited resource contexts like iOS?

Comment: Adding an array controller for each table, as far as I know, is a good choice. Array controllers make KVO extraordinarily simple and tables "love" this.